# How to remove UWP Cordova (Ionic) title bar arrow, and perhaps app title?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, uwp

I have a Cordova (Ionic 2) application running on Windows 10 (UWP), I am using Visual Studio 2017 to build the Cordova project.

The hosting window as an arrow, which looks completely out of place, especially if when I am in child views and the Ionic status bar already has a back arrow.

Here the arrow I am talking about

[image]

Does anyone know how to remove or hide this?

Also maybe the application title (though this is not as big a issue)

Thanks in advance!

As suggested by @Sunteen Wu - MSFT, the following solved my problem...

```
     private hideWindowsTitleBackArrow() : void {
        try {
          let w : any = window;
          if (w.cordova.platformId == "windows") {
              let currentView = w.Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.getForCurrentView();
              currentView.appViewBackButtonVisibility = w.Windows.UI.Core.AppViewBackButtonVisibility.collapsed;
          }      
        } catch (error) {
           this.logger.error(`Error in hideWindowsTitleBackArrow: ${error}`);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the following codes in cordova to disable the back button:

```
if (cordova.platformId = "windows")
{
    var currentView = Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.getForCurrentView();
    currentView.appViewBackButtonVisibility = Windows.UI.Core.AppViewBackButtonVisibility.collapsed;
}
```

More details please reference [`SystemNavigationManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.systemnavigationmanager) class.

Comment: Thanks for the above, do you know where (what source file) I put this? Looking in the project (in Visual Studio), I surprisingly see no C# code anywhere, only JS code (unless I can put in in there somehow?)

Comment: Actually, all good, I found it on the windows object, and this works! I just adding in the  `platform.ready()` call within in the `app.component` constructor, Thanks!

Comment: @peterc please help me, I try the above code in my ionic3 app but I get an error on "Windows.UI.Core" that Cannot find name 'Windows' please help me how can you use the above code in my app.

Comment: @Neotrixs - I have added the code I used at the bottom of the question (so it is formatted), and I just call this after the `platform.ready()` has resolved, ie  `await this.platform.ready(); this.hideWindowsTitleBackArrow();`