# How to remove UWP Ionic title bar arrow?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, uwp

I have the exact same setup as the poster in this question:

[How to remove UWP Cordova (Ionic) title bar arrow, and perhaps app title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019747/how-to-remove-uwp-cordova-ionic-title-bar-arrow-and-perhaps-app-title)

I dont understand where the accepted answer code goes or what imports are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the comments of the accepted answer. It should go into the Ionic platform `ready()` call ([see documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#ready)) . You should have access to the `Windows` namespace from within JS, the code in the answer might look like C#, but it actually is JS. It uses the  [`SystemNavigationManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.systemnavigationmanager)'s `AppViewBackButtonVisibility` property to hide the back button.

Comment: Do I have to import something? That code does not compile when I add it to ready(). "Cannot find name Windows"

Comment: That is very unusual, it should be available if the app targets UWP. Could you try the following plugin - https://github.com/bambam2174/cordova-plugin-uwpbackbutton ?

Comment: @matin-Zikmund still no luck. Appreciate your help with this though. I have to put this project on hold for a few weeks. I'll update as soon as I get back to it.

Comment: @MartinZikmund Had a solution? I have the same issue.